# How to disable Roll reading backwards from a bno055 sensor when it is out of the angle range?

Tags: python, sensors, adafruit, adafruit-circuitpython

I am using adafruit_bno055 python library to move a servo based on the Roll reading from the sensor. It works perfectly in the range, which is from -90 to 90 degrees. But when I roll the sensor further back, it starts to read the angle in decreasing order rather None, such as when I moved it to 100 degrees physically, it read 80. How can I disable this?

I have tried to check on the adafruit_bno055 library, but could not find a way to do it.

Comment: That's the way the sensor (and angles) work. You cannot disable it. You should think about how to use the sensor as it is designed instead of trying to make the sensor behave how you think.